# Accessing native android methods from webview

Tags: android, mysql, webview, gps, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch 2 app running in an Android webview, and when the user touches a button in the view, I would like to run a java method. Specifically, I want to begin updating the users location every x minutes and store it in a database. My first problem is that I am not sure how (if its even possible) to call my GPS/location method from the webview. The second problem is that I do not know how to make sure I am storing the location values for the correct user, since the login takes place in the webview. I looked into `addJavascriptInterface` to call my GPS method, but how would I associate the native location information with the user's web login?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at technologies like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com), that provide a bridge between JavaScript and Native. There are alternatives, of course (Titanium, Corona, Intel XDK), but PhoneGap (or Cordova), are quite widely used - and free (Intel's solution is free as well - for now).

PhoneGap supports access to a device's GPS, among other things.

Comment: This is not the answer I had been looking for, however I ended up having to go totally Sencha Touch for this project. Phonegap with Sencha has been great to work with, and I love it, but Sencha Touch does have a steep learning curve in my opinion.

Comment: Steep learning curve + ExtJS + a price (for the advanced features) = no go for me.